# How is this size computed?

Tags: c++

5.1.1/2 is stated that:

> The keyword `this` names a pointer to the object for which a
>   non-static member function (9.3.2) is invoked or a non-static data
>   member’s initializer (9.2) is evaluated.

And:

> Unlike the object expression in other contexts, `*this` is not
>   required to be of complete type for purposes of class member access
>   (5.2.5) outside the member function body.

The following code prints `8`:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

struct Test
{
    std::size_t sz = sizeof(this->sz);
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << Test{}.sz;
}
```

5.3.3 says:

> The operand is either an expression, which is an unevaluated operand
>   (Clause 5), or a parenthesized *type-id*. The `sizeof` operator shall
>   not be applied to an expression that has function or incomplete
>   type...

`sizeof this->sz` has the same result.

Is `this->` considered a no-op in this case and it's essentially equivalent to `sizeof(sz)`?

Comment: There are very few (one actually) case where using `this->` for member access makes a difference, and this is not one of them.

Comment: `(*this).sz` is a complete type isn't it, `std::size_t`? You got to it by derefencing this, but I'm not sure why you expect that matters.

Answer (score 9):

> Is `this->` considered a no-op in this case and it's essentially equivalent to `sizeof(sz)`?

**That's right.**

The type of `this->sz` is `std::size_t`, a complete type in that context.

The type of `*this` is *not* complete here, but you quoted the passage stating why that doesn't matter and we can go straight through to analysing `sz` specifically.

As such, the `this->` had no actual effect on the semantics of the expression, either for better or for worse.

As Sergey said, there is one case where using `this->` for member access makes a difference (template bases!), and this is not one of them.